# prolog language list division

Tags: prolog

i've started learn prolog language and this came out

i can't even understand this practice problem

```
conc([],L,L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
    conc(L1,L2,L3).

length([], 0).
length([_|Tail],K) :-
     length(Tail,K1),
     K is 1 + K1.
```

i have to define rule "dividelist"
using "conc" and "length"

and the rule "dividelist" works like this

```
?- dividelist([a,b,c,d,e],[a,c,e],[b,d]).
true .
?- dividelist([a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c],[d,e]).
false.
```

it will be so thankful if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

The rule that I can see, which makes most sense **to me**, is this: *the second and third lists' elements alternate, producing the first list, starting with the second one*. If this is true, the predicate `dividelist` can be easily written even without the use of `conc` and `length`:

```
dividelist([], [], []).
dividelist([A], [A], []).

dividelist([A, B | R], [A | R1], [B | R2]) :- dividelist(R, R1, R2).
```

However, this may not be the true answer, but I am unable to see other reasonable rules only from two given examples.

Comment: Clause ```dividelist([A, B], [A], [B]).``` must be excluded from the definition, since clause ```dividelist([A, B | R], [A | R1], [B | R2]) :- dividelist(R, R1, R2).``` already solves this case. Otherwise, query ```?- dividelist([a,b,c,d],A,B).``` will produce redundant answer: ```A = [a, c], B = [b, d]  ; A = [a, c], B = [b, d].```.

Comment: @slago True, I totally oversaw this. It's been removed from the answer. Thanks for noticing and notifying me.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me.
appreciate you.
can i ask one more favor please?
can you help me with define rule "dividelist" with using only "conc" and "length"?
kinda tough problem to me,
sorry for asking again.

Comment: @김민규 Well, I guess you could do it like this if you _really_ wanted to use `conc` and `length`, but it just makes the code unnecessarily confusing:

`dividelist([], [], []).`
`dividelist([A], [A], []).`
`dividelist(L, L1, L2) :- length(L, LL), length(L1, LL1), length(L2, LL2),  LL =:= LL1 + LL2, L1 = [A | R1], L2 = [B | R2], dividelist(T, R1, R2), conc([A, B], T, L).`

I highly recommend avoiding this method in the future, and instead coming up with "cleaner code" like in the answer above.